# Object.Assign returns value as an array, require as an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

Should be a quick fix for a whiz (I am sadly not that!) Im struggling with some manipulation of some json (underneath code). I'm trying to create a new key value pair named 'dollar_price'. This would be achieved by multiplying the 'price' and 'index_price' values. I am able to do the multiplication and inserting the newly created key and value into the json but for some reason it inserts the value as its own array.

```
var result = result.map(function(el) {
            var dp = Object.assign({}, el);

            //I tried the line below as well but no luck :( 
            //var dp = Object.assign.apply(Object, [{}].concat(el));

              dp.dollar_price = result.map(({price, index_price}) => price * index_price);
              return dp;
           });
```

JSON current output:

```
{ price: 5,
  index_price: 20,
  dollar_price: [100],
  key3: value3
}
```

The intended output should be:

```
{ price: 5,
  index_price: 20,
  dollar_price: 100,
  key3: value3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{
  price: 5,
  index_price: 20,
  key3: 1
}]

var result = data.map(pr => ({...pr, dollar_price: pr.price * pr.index_price}));

console.log(result );
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just do this

```
dp.dollar_price = result.map(({price, index_price}) => price * index_price)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
      f=(_)=>({..._,dollar_price:_.price*_.index_price})
      console.log(data.map(f))
```